# How to make the Windows 8 trackpad edge swipe zones smaller?

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, gestures

I'm running Windows 8 on a Lenovo x220 laptop; and have just inadvertently discovered the edge-swipe feature or that brings up the charms or switches between desktop and RT. Only problem is that the landing zones are a little too wide for my liking - I'd like to keep this feature, but to narrow the zone where it can start. I'd rather not disable it completely as per:
[Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop)

The Synaptic driver (latest available) doesn't seem to provide for changing this (though it does for other zones). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to achieve this before asking the question you are linking to. After playing around in the registry for some time, I think I have found the solution!

- Open up *Run*.

  - Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> *or* press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and select *Run*.
- Type *regedit* and press *Ok*.
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2_3\`
  or something similar. It may be a bit different depending on driver version, vendor etc.
- Select the *edge swipe* you want to modify.
- Take a screenshot (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>prt scr</kbd>) to save the values you will be editing in case you mess something up.
- Modify the *LoXRel*, *HiXRel*, *LoYRel* and/or *HiYRel* values. What needs to be modified depends on the edge.
- Restart the computer, check if the zone is right or try again.

**Example:**
Here I have modified the *Top Edge Pull*-zone to not go so far down from the edge. The value I need to change is the *LoYRel*. The higher the value, the smaller the zone ("how far from the bottom the lower part of the zone should end"). I've changed it to be *ffffffff* (the max) which means that it will only do a *Top Edge Pull* when I start with my finger entirely from the top edge, and not when I start closer to the middle. The default value was *fffff060* which left some (too much) room on the top, now I don't accidentally do edge gestures/swipe all the time.

[image: how to edit zone]

**NB!**
When playing around with the values, don't set them *too extreme* just to check if you're editing the right value. I managed to make my entire touchpad an edge-zone. :p

Comment: Any way to this without restarting the computer each time?

Comment: Not as I know. You can try killing the synaptic processes and restart them. But did you try the method?

Comment: Yep; works like a charm (if you pardon the pun)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Lenovo will also likely update their drivers to support Windows 8.  I suggest you report this problem to Lenovo so they can update their general trackpad drivers.  All their devices use the same device ( more/less ).

Comment: any idea what the difference is between Right Edge Pull and Right Edge Pull Extended Zone??

Comment: @qntmfred I'm afraid I don't.