# Reduce touchpad area for left edge swipe gesture in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, gestures

So this question is similar but different to the question [Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop), or at least the "modify" portion of the question was never addressed. 
I've managed to get the left edge swipe gesture working on my Synaptics touchpad through some registry edits- it seems that everyone is suggestion the exact same changes across various websites, so if you've solved the same problem the entries below probably look familiar. The problem is that the left edge swipe activation area is much too big and I trigger it by accident far more often than any of the other edge gestures. I'm assuming that the registry values are defining the box on the touchpad that activates the gesture, but I'm not entirely sure what all the dwords are doing. Here are the current registry entries for left edge swipe (from export):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Left Edge Pull]
"ConfigFlags"=dword:00000101
"PalmCheckFlags"=dword:00000000
"ConfigFlagsEx"=dword:00000400
"LoXRel"=dword:00000000
"HiXRel"=dword:00001388
"LoYRel"=dword:00001388
"HiYRel"=dword:ffffec78
"LoXFlags"=dword:00000010
"HiXFlags"=dword:0000000a
"LoYFlags"=dword:00000004
"HiYFlags"=dword:00000004
"SliderFriction"=dword:00000000
"ActionType"=dword:00000002
"SliderScale"=dword:00000080
```

Any idea how to shrink the size of the activation area vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [the same basic approach taken here](https://superuser.com/questions/498121/how-to-make-the-windows-8-trackpad-edge-swipe-zones-smaller) I just modified the `HiXRel` to be half of it's original value. 
As a bonus, I also shrunk the right edge swipe zone which required increasing the `LoXRel` value under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTPEnh\ZoneConfig\TouchPadPS2\Left Edge Pull`. I just split the difference between the original value and the maximum value and added it to the original value. 
Hope this helps anyone else who runs into the same problem