# How to make Skype not come into the view on Windows 8 every couple of minutes?

Tags: windows-8, alt-tab

I am using a Lenovo Yoga 13 with Windows 8 on it, and right now if I use the desktop, I don't know whether it is due to the trackpad's sensitivity and its "feature", or is it Win 8 doing it, the screen often switch to Skype (or other Win 8 app) which is a Win 8 app (not a desktop app).

So I always have to switch back to the desktop and it is one of the things that is extremely annoying.  Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact it is exactly the same issue on [Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop)

I solved it in fact using the solution of going to the Control Panel, choose Mouse Settings, and the last tab can let me fine tune the Synaptics trackpad's settings.  I just disabled "Edge Swipe" and now it never happens.