# Changing Windows 8 edge swipe behavior

Tags: windows-8, touchpad

I’d like to use the edge swiping feature of windows 8 to open the start menu instead of the charm bar.

I found that, and wonder if there’s a way to change that behavior using regedit :
[Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop)
There is only information on how to disable it, but not to change it.

Thanks in advance,
Silver Duck

Comment: Change it to what exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound "to open the start menu instead".

Comment: There are applications that modify this behavior. Unless there already is a gesture to open start menu its unlikely what you want is possible. You can change which gesture does what the gesture has to be something that is supported. The supported gestures are likely documented on Microsoft's website, I would find that documentation, and at that point somebody can answer this question. I am supported by this article: http://www.howtogeek.com/135507/how-can-i-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-my-laptop/ which clearly indicates that the ActionType value determines what happens. Trial and error.

Comment: Note that the *ActionType* values in the useful article linked to by @Ramhound are most likely for Synaptics touchpads only.

Comment: Thanks,

I’m not sure about the ActionType thing. For example, both LeftEdgePull and RightEdgePull have the same ActionType value, but don’t do the same thing…

I’m still investigating, but nobody seems to have a clue on the internet…

I’ll let you know if I find something.

@+

Comment: @SilverDuck - Its likely not documented to be honest.  As Karan points out even then I have only seen these swipe motions supported by Synaptics touchpads ( or at least articles and questions on Synaptics touchpads ).