# Accidentally (?) disabled touchpad scrolling

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, touchpad, scrolling

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Z580 with Windows 8, and I was annoyed by the charms bar popping up every time I was putting my finger on the touchpad from the right side, so I applied the registry changes suggested in the accepted answer to [Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop) .

I made the changes directly in the registry, and now I'm thinking I might have accidentally changed also another value, since moving my finger on the right side does not scroll anymore, and the scroll options are completely disabled (greyed out) in the touchpad settings.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers (Synaptics ClickPad V8.1), but that did not solve my problem :(

Any suggestions for a quick fix or the registry values I should check?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you didn't make a backup of your registry before editing it- it would've taken 5 seconds to backup the branch you were working on and saved you an hour of forums and troubleshooting.

The next best option is a system restore to the most recent restore point before you changed anything.

Comment: Yes, I self-kicked enough about that :) ... but since it's not a major problem, it would be nice to be able to recover without restoring the system

Comment: Kim Jong-Un is disappoint.