# Disable startscreen *being triggered* by touchpad/mouse

Tags: windows-8, mouse, touchpad, start-screen

I happily run stock Windows 8 on my own devices, i am not another "i do not get/like the start screen" whiner.

A laptop running windows 8.0 is hooked up to a 2nd display (LED wall, or a beamer) to which video output is cloned. The problem here is that whenever the user triggers the start screen, this disrupts the cloned output and content shown on that LED wall is replaced by the start screen or goes black.

This gets annoying soon, for all users of that LED wall. Is there any way to make sure that the start screen is:

- not triggered by touch pad edges
- not triggered by moving mouse in corner

In Windows 7 and prior, the start menu would be a non-issue since its not full screen, and our content window is set to "Always on top".

Comment: Can you set it to work in the *extended desktop* mode instead of *clone desktop*?

Comment: No, that is not an option here.

Comment: Based upon your comments, see if this helps  [Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop)

Comment: Thanks @DaveRook that does answer the touch pad half of the question. The website does not allow me to accept/upvote your comment though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Start8](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/) or some other Start Screen replacement for Windows 8. (there are many of those, Start8 is just the first that popped up in Google - I haven't tested it myself).

Comment: I do not want to get rid of the start screen or replace it, i just don't want it to popup accidentally by screen/touchpad edges.

Comment: @DaveRook So you say there no registry setting or option in Windows to disable the touchpad swipes triggering the startscreen?

Comment: @user2096041 No, I'm saying you clearly have more requirements than your post, hence why when people give suggestions you're saying it's not an option! I think you need to edit your post to make it clearer. Your comment here does make it clear (that you just want want to disable touch pad swipes).

Answer (score 0):

Touchpad gestures disabled as per
[Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop)

and for mouse gestures i know of no solution besides using Start8 (commercial product)