# Turning off touchpad multi gesture in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, gestures

I have an Asus A55V laptop with Windows 8 installed on it. Now I'm trying to turn off the Touchpad gestures. On Superuser I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/495379/138343):

> However, after experimenting with drivers I found a Synaptics driver from ASUS that comes with something they call ASUS Smart Gesture. There, under the Edge Gesture tab one can disable the different swipe gestures. Easier and safer than messing with the registry.
>
> However this only works for ASUS computers, while Daniel B's answer should work for most Synaptic touchpads.

But how do I find Asus Smart Gesture on my laptop? I only found it in the registry but there is no Edge Gesture Tab. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The best guess I've got right now is that the version of *Asus Smart Gesture* on your laptop isn't exactly up to date.

Try looking for an online version of the software, perhaps this is [suitable](http://www.asus.com/my/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/A55VD#support_Download_36) it is under the **Touchpad (2)** link.

Once downloaded, unzip and install the software, reboot your computer if necessary and then try following typical instructions

> There, under the Edge Gesture tab one can disable the different swipe gestures.

-Cheers, Hope I helped. :D