# How to disable action bar top edge swipe?

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, action-center

I just got a Dell Inspiron 13 2-in-1 with Windows 10. It's great, but I hate trying to touch the top of the screen and accidentally making the Action Center pop out. I like the Action Center, and I like how I can swipe in from the right edge to make it appear, but is there any way to disable the top edge swipe so I stop opening it by accident?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look if [this](https://superuser.com/a/494709/587060) post on SuperUser will help you (Includes Registry changes etc).

But if it doesnt work, there is another comment on the same thread, different approach :

> For my Dell, I went to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices
>   and Printers. Right click on the laptop picture and select Mouse
>   Settings. Click on Dell Touchpad, and in that screen select the link
>   that says "Click to change DellTouchpad settings". Go to Gestures.
>
> Swipe options are listed on this screen.

IF All fails try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889683/how-do-i-turn-off-windows-8-1-gestures-and-setting-charm-bar-on-my-touch-screen) very elaborate solution

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please, when providing links, [explain the content inside them](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) making at least a brief summary of the relevant information that can be found in them.